# Can "veut" be used to mean anger or resent in this context?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

I'm a novice with the language and I've been reading some Asterix to practice my understanding of it, I usually go back and forth between the English and French version to make sure I got things right, along with checking a dictionary.

[image]

From this panel I understand that Numérobis' rival (Amonbofis) either likes that Numérobis got chosen in his place so that his career may end with him being eaten by a crocodile or that he resents him for being chosen in his place and would be pleased if his career ended with him being eaten by a crocodile, what throws me off is the "Veut", could you please help me understand it a bit more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*“[En vouloir à quelqu’un](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir)”* means (definition B):

> Éprouver de l'hostilité, du ressentiment, de la rancune à l'égard de quelqu'un.

That is:

> To feel hostility, resentment, rancour towards someone.

So Amonbofis feels resentment towards Numérobis for being chosen in his place to construct Caesar’s palace.

Note that to make sure on which meaning to give it in the future, you should pay attention to ***en*** before the verb *vouloir*.

> vouloir → to want, to desire
>   **en** vouloir à quelqu’un → to be angry at someone

But then again, *“en vouloir”* could also sometimes mean *“to desire”*, when **en** is a pronoun put in to point at something or someone already made mention of:

> — Veux-tu des bonbons ? → *Do you want candies?*
>   — J’**en** veux ! → *I do (want **some**)*

Comment: Your clarification on the use of "en" is just what I needed to understand this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Il faut faire la différence entre : "en vouloir à quelqu'un" qui veut dire qu'on éprouve du ressentiment contre cette personne et "en vouloir" et "en vouloir encore" ... qui est une réponse à une proposition. "Tu veux des bonbons?" "Oui, j'en veux." et après, si on nous en repropose  ..."oui, j'en veux encore".